# Haskell GHC create executable not depending on GMP?

Tags: haskell

I have a simple program that doesn't appear to use libgmp at all.

```
-- Sample.hs
main = putStrLn "hi"
```

If I compile it using the default options on Linux

```
$ ghc Sample.hs
```

This produces an executable called `Sample`. I wanted to see what libraries were required by a simple program that doesn't make use of arbitrary precision integers.

```
$ ldd Sample | sed -e 's/[(].*[)]/(0x000...)/'
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x000...)
        libgmp.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libgmp.so.10 (0x000...)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x000...)
        librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x000...)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x000...)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x000...)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000...)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x000...)
```

Is there some flag I can pass to GHC to tell it not to produce an executable depending on the `libgmp.so` library. I don't want to statically link libgmp in, ideally I'd like to configure GHC not to emit code that depends on that library at all. I'm okay with some reduced functionality such as an error if I attempt to use an `Integer` or something like that.

Comment: If you're worried about the LGPL license note that all you need to do to comply to that is A: Not ship your binaries (e.g. common case of running a webserver) or B: Just ship object code along with your binaries; All you need to do to comply with LGPL is to allow people to link against a different compatible version of the LGPL library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not at all sure of this, but it seems likely that you can do it by telling GHC to use `integer-simple` instead of `integer-gmp` when you build GHC. Specifically, configure `INTEGER_LIBRARY=integer-simple`. See `mk/config.mk.in` in the GHC source tree.

Comment: Yes, I've done that before and it works fine... except for a few libraries that depend on `integer-gmp`.  Text was one of those up till I patched it (and then someone fixed my patch).  Sadly the set of packages doing this seems to be [growing](http://packdeps.haskellers.com/reverse/integer-gmp).

Comment: @ThomasMDuBuisson, that list includes `bytestring`, which is pretty critical. If it really depends on `integer-gmp`, that'll block up an awful lot of other libraries.

Comment: It, and several others, have an integer-simple flag.

Comment: Perhaps a bit off-topic, but I thought ghc was migrating to shake. Is the shake-based build system going to honor the same environment variables?

Comment: @GregoryNisbet, GHC is migrating to Shake (I think that's expected to happen in 8.4). I don't know how the configuration options will work, but I'm confident you'll be able to set them one way or another! It may still be done with `configure`, for all I know.